# Can "learning as they went" be omitted from this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Found no results containing "as they went," so I thought I would ask this question.

About the sentence "The MagikMe founders did not start out as business professionals: they were parents who became professionals, learning *as they went*" - will it make sense even if we drop the *as they went* part?

Comment: It's a little unclear whether you are asking if all of the sub-clause 'learning as they went' or just the last three words 'as they went' can be omitted.

Comment: Yes, that works and finishing with something like '...were just parents who learned their business skills as they went along' conveys the sense that they picked things up along the way without getting any formal business training.

Comment: Why are you considering dropping it at all?  What would be gained?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "learning as they went" adds information to the sentence. If it is removed the sentence is valid but does not tell the reader how they obtained their (presumed — I have never heard of them) proficiency.

The phrase (often used in an expanded form — "as they went *along*") implies that they "learnt on the job" — from experience of doing whatever it is they do — rather than from formal training.

Comment: @MárcioOsório — You're welcome